# Why might third-party extension be missing from Extensions dialog of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, installation, extensions

I have just installed a third-party extension to ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 ([Land Change Modeler for ArcGIS 2.0](https://clarklabs.org/land-change-modeler-for-arcgis/), essentially IDRISI ported to ArcGIS, as far as I know). There were no error messages during installation, and nothing to indicate that the extension was not installed properly. Yet, when I opened ArcMap and tried to activate the extension, it was not one of the choices under Customize --> Extensions.

Obviously, ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 is blissfully unaware that LCM is installed on my machine. Is there any way to manually register the extension with ArcGIS? Both the LCM an the ArcGIS files are installed in folders in the Program Files (x86) directory. Clark Labs, the maker of the extension, told me that this (and not somewhere inside the ArcGIS folder, for example) is the right location for them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular extension, but can you confirm that it is supposed to be an extension (Customize > Extensions) and not a toolbar/add-in (Customize > Toolbars)?

Comment: If it is supposed to be an add-in and not an extension, I've never heard of this. In any case, I don't see it under Customize > Toolbars, either.

Comment: I tried adding the extension through Customize > Add-In Manager > Customize > Add From File. Browsing to the files with my would-be extension in them, I tried every single .dll file. Usually the message I got was "Can't load type library from the specified file." However, when I clicked on lcm.dll, the message was different ("The program can't start because borlndmm.dll is missing from your computer.") The suggestion was to re-install the program to fix this. Now, borlndmm.dll IS present on my computer, in the LCM files. However, the last update to the file was in 2002. An old version, maybe?

Comment: Just depends how it is built. Did you look in the toolbars?

Answer (score 1):

If you continue to have problems with this, then my recommendation would be to uninstall both Land Change Modeler for ArcGIS 2.0 and ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop, and then re-install ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop followed by Land Change Modeler for ArcGIS 2.0.

By doing that you will either have solved your problem, or to at least be in a better position to talk to Clark Labs about the install of their extension on your fresh install of ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I would also recommend that you record the precise steps that you perform to Land Change Modeler for ArcGIS 2.0 so that you can describe in detail what you tried to both Clark Labs and here.

Answer (score 0):

Bing translation:

> If an extension is easy to add, in the ArcToolBox you give Add Toolbox
>   and looks for the location of the extension (the direction of
>   installation that was given during the installation). Then found the
>   extension you select and give add; then will appear in the list of the
>   ArcToolbox.

---

Si es una extensión es fácil de agregar, en el ArcToolBox le das Add Toolbox y busca la ubicación de la extensión (la dirección de instalación que se le dio durante la instalación). Luego encontrada la extensión se seleccionas y le das agregar; luego se te aparecerá en la lista del ArcToolbox.